# what is pushstate in html5?

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, pushstate

can anyone tell me what pushstate in html 5 is?
also can you tell me how can i push data to a html5 page?
I am planing to make a chat application using html5 and jquerymobile and phonegap.

Answer (score 3):

PushState used for Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page.

please visit the following link for more info.

**[pushState!](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)**

Comment: i asked this a few months back, the ans is use websockets. :)